# How to order the best match at first with multiple keywords in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

If I have keywords tree, cow and mouse

I want to order rows from database that will return the best match at first which has the biggest number if keywords contained in it

For example:

1. the cow loves the mouse and the tree
2. the mouse is on the tree
3. tree

Can I do this?!

Comment: You could use this function: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/counting-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string.aspx

Comment: Or this; http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/02/2460.aspx - Give either a try first and then ask a more specific question if you run into problems!

Answer (score 0):

You should use fulltext search containstable

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx